# You can't use `\eqno' in math mode. \end{equation} and Missing } inserted. \end{equation}

Tags: equations, errors

i'm trying to write this equation but LateX give me these errors. I already find similar question but any of them can solve the problem. Any suggestions?

```
\begin{equation}
\rho(X,Y) = {{{E(XY) - E(X)-E(Y)}\over{\sqrt{var(X)var(Y)}}}
\end{equation}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing `}` at the end of the equation. Or rather, a couple of extra `{`. You could simplify the input to:

```latex
\begin{equation}
\rho(X,Y) = {E(XY) - E(X)-E(Y) \over \sqrt{var(X)var(Y)}}
\end{equation}
```

because the syntax for `\over` is `{<subformula> \over <subformula>}`, without the need of extra braces around the `<subformula>`s.

With proper LaTeX syntax and dedicated operators for `E` and `var`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\rho(X,Y) = \frac{\E(XY)-\E(X)-\E(Y)}{\sqrt{\var(X)\var(Y)}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: thank you very much @Phelype! really clear explanation!!

Comment: @Elisam You're welcome. Glad it helped :-)